# How to make firebase 3 work with a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebase-realtime-database

I have this simple chrome extension and i'm trying to add firebase, but for some reason i get:

```
chrome-extension://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=__iframefcb195969 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

here is the code sample: https://github.com/patrioticcow/testint_chrome

firebase docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/

any ideas?

Comment: I believe you need to actually include it in your `manifest.json` under [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration)

Comment: already tried that

Comment: The `firebase.js` script included with your extension contains some calls to `//apis.google.com/js/client.js`. The protocol is not specified, so it calls `chrome-extension://apis.google.com/js/client.js` which does not exist. You could either load `firebase.js` from a CDN so that it uses `https` automatically or you might try manually modifying your copy of `firebase.js` to include `https:` in these calls (there are only 2 of them). I was able to get rid of your error this way, but your extension still didn't work. I have no knowledge of Firebase so I can't help with that any further.

Comment: seen this sample? if still not working ping me. my chrome extension uses firebase fine but i had to hack it a bit to get it working. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-chrome-extension/tree/master/src

Comment: @PetrSrníček You have a point, but now i get `iframe.js:84 Uncaught Error: This domain is not authorized for OAuth operations for your Firebase project. Edit the list of authorized domains from the Firebase console` not sure what URL to white-list..very annoying

Answer (score 0):

you need to whitelist your chrome extension in Firebase using

> `chrome-extension://<your chrome app ID>`